# Why create-react-native-app does not has ios and android files anymore?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am learning react native. i need to access to android and ios files so i can add maps to my app, but i cant find them!

i tried looking inside assets file, node modules file. but could not find them.

[image: this is an image showing my project files]

Comment: Note that `create-react-native-app` module has been archived.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve created your app with `Expo`.

`Expo` abstracts away the native code, meaning that you don’t have to deal with it. So this means that no matter how hard you look inside an `Expo` app you won’t find any native code.

This can be beneficial if you don’t have access to a Mac for iOS development. It also means that you only need to write in Javascript and not worry about writing code in java or objective-c.

However, `Expo` has access to maps in it. Check out `MapView` it uses Apple and Google maps to display maps in your app, so you don’t need to add another dependency. 
https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/map-view/

It’s very straight forward to use. You don’t have to install anything you can just import from `Expo` here is a sample

```
import React from 'react';
import { MapView } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
     return (
      <MapView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          initialRegion={{
          latitude: 37.78825,
          longitude: -122.4324,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to have access to the native code you either have to create your app using `react-native init YourAppName` or you can eject your `Expo`

To eject your app run `expo eject` in the terminal.

You can read more about it here : https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/

There are pros and cons for ejecting. But if you need access to native code then you will have to eject.

Comment: I develop on a Mac and found myself ejecting from Expo 100% of the time. Great answer.